# Typo in scope operator leads to unexpected compile and recursion in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a class structure like this:

```
class A{

    public:
    void foo();

};

class B: public A{

    public:
    void foo();

};
```

The implementation of B::foo() is like:

```
void B::foo(){

   A:foo();

}
```

Clearly, I made a mistake typing '::', but the compiler didn't complain.  When I ran the program, it ran as if I had typed:

```
void B::foo(){

   foo();

}
```

Can anybody explain this within the C++ standard?  Is it really valid code, or a likely bug in the compiler (MS Visual Studio 2012) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A:` a label, for use with a `goto` statememt.

```
void B::foo(){
   goto A;
   std::cout << "this will be skipped";
   A:foo();
}
```